# Basic c++ : for-each loop

Tags: c++, foreach

I have been learning C++ for a couple of weeks, and am sorry for my basic question but this question seems too hard to find its answers to in google or on this SO site. 
I am learning to code modern C++ in VS 2015  and I can do something like this (my friend's code)

```
for each (int i in vectorOfInt)
{
   // do something
}
```

But after searching a lot from this 
http://en.cppreference.com/

I still can't find its syntax. I asked him and he said, his teacher wrote so.
Is it part of C++? Since when it becomes available? As I can't find it in my latest C++ book (Bjarne's) also.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that! The VS-specific "for each" syntax isn't in the linked question.

Comment: Exactly! 
Boys! read things before answering.

Comment: Oh, don't take it personally please - there are a lot of questions here and it's easy to make mistakes.

Comment: Sorry @MegumiBear: you wrote that you were learning the syntax of the language, and wrote some stuff that looked like pseudocode a teacher might have written. I had no idea that stuff actually compiles on VS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a non-standard microsoft extension for C++ and C++/CLI

[for each, in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177202.aspx)

> Iterates through an array or collection. This non-standard keyword is available in both C++/CLI and native C++ projects. However, its use is not recommended. Consider using a standard Range-based for Statement (C++) instead.

Comment: This is the answer! Thanks crashmstr

Comment: Wow. I use VS for years (if not decades) now and this feature is available since VS 2005 at least. I guess that back then it seemed like a good idea to offer a for-each. But then the committee decided to make a range based for a simple "for".